# Convertir/pasar una aplicación hecha de Windows Form (C#) a aplicación de consola

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, aplicación-escritorio

Tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms en la que al ejecutarse va comprobando cada 2 segundos si hay una aplicación abierta (Por ejemplo, el Notepad++), y si pasa esto, muestra un mensaje de alerta o simplemente se cierre la aplicación. Pero claro, en este caso no hace ninguna falta que al ejecutarse la aplicación se abra un formulario, ya que no hay interacción con él.

Necesito hacer lo mismo pero con aplicación de consola, por ejemplo, que al ejecutarse esté ahí en segundo plano comprobando cada segundo y cuando pase eso, cerrarse o mostrar alerta o lo que sea; o incluso que con winform, al ejecutarse la aplicación que no muestre el formulario o que se haga en segundo plano sin necesidad de que lo vea el usuario.

Mi código de WinForms:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temporizador1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Close();
         temporizador1.Stop();
         MessageBox.Show("Se ha abierto la aplicación.");
    }
```

¿Hay forma de hacer esto o es demasiada locura?

Saludos.

Comment: Si. hay forma.. con restricciones. La de consola no va a poder mostrar un cartel. y la otra, podria vivir sin un form..

Comment: ¿Y cómo sería vivir sin un form?

Comment: Sin levantar un formulario. Tu codigo levanta una clase form.. sin embargo una app que viva en la barra de tareas por ejemplo no levanta por defecto un formulario.

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es un [Servicio de Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

Comment: una duda, sino hay interaccion porque muestras un MessageBox ? eso es interaccion, podrias ocultar el form al System Tray (un icono que esta al lado del reloj de la barra de tarea), no se si eso te serviria?

Comment: Eso eso, eso es justamente lo que necesitaría @LeandroTuttini

Comment: Hay formas de crear aplicaciones winforms sin crear formularios, busca información sobre la clase ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que el form no se este visualizando todo el tiempo puedes llevar la aplicacion al System Tray, el icono al lado del reloj de la barra de tarea en windows

[How to Show NotifyIcon in Windows Forms Application Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/how-to-show-notifyicon-in-windows-forms-application-using-C-Sharp/)

[NotifyIcon](https://www.dotnetperls.com/notifyicon)

Para poder implementarlo tienes un control de nombre `NotifyIcon`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde codigo solo tienes que definir

```
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

true/false si quiere llevar la aplicacion al system tray

Es mas podras reemplazar el MessageBox por un `BalloonTip`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Add a Notify Icon to the System Tray with C#](http://www.daveoncsharp.com/2009/08/add-notify-icon-to-system-tray/)

usando

```
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip()
```

Comment: La notificación me funciona correctamente pero me sigue sin ocultar el formulario.

Comment: ¿Has probado a añadir `this.ShowInTaskbar = true` en la carga del formulario?